# переключение по

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Canvas workshop</title>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #line {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #line1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  
  #line2 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: thistle;
  }
  
  #line3 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  
  #line4 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: thistle;
  }
  
  #line5 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  
  #line6 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: thistle;
  }
  
  .pic_push_down {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-Right: 50%;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="line">
    <div id="line1">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic1'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic2'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic3'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line4">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic4'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line5">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic5'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line6">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic6'></p>
    </div>

  </div><br>
  <div align="center">
    <button onClick="left_button()"><=</button>
    <button onClick="right_button()">=></button>
    <br>
  </div>


  <script>
    document.onkeypress = function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }
    document.mousedown = function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }
    var i = 1;
    var pic = document.getElementById('pic' + i).innerHTML = '<img id="cockerel.png" src="cockerel.png" width="50px">';

    function left_button() {
      if (i < 6) {
        i++;
      }

    }

    function right_button() {
      if (i > 6) {
        i--;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Почему то не получается переключать объект между блоками. Что делать? функция left_button() и right_button() не срабатывает. Как поставить при нажатии кнопки переключение на левый или правый блок? Все обыскал нигде такого решения нету.

Answer (score 2):

> Все обыскал нигде такого решения нету.

Плохо/не правильно искали, решений полно. В вашем коде разбираться не стал т.к. практически ничего и нет, и ошибок много.
Вот вам пример:

```js
var carousel = function (){
    return {
      init: function(elem){
      let link = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Rooster02.jpg',
   img = '<img id="image" src="'+link+'" width="50px">';
      this.setImage(img);
      document.onkeydown = this.checkKey;
    },
    setImage: function(imageNode){
     document.getElementById('pic1').innerHTML = imageNode;
    },
    checkKey: function (e){
      e = e || window.event;
      let pictures = document.getElementById('line').querySelectorAll('.pic_push_down'),
          pictLength = pictures.length,
        nextButton = document.querySelector('#nextButton'),
          prevButton = document.querySelector('#prevButton'),
          image = document.querySelector('#image'),
          current = image.closest('p.pic_push_down').parentElement;
      if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       let prevElem = current.previousElementSibling;
        if (prevElem) {
         prevElem.querySelector('p.pic_push_down').prepend(image);
        } else {
         pictures[pictLength-1].prepend(image);
        }
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       let nextElem = current.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextElem) {
         nextElem.querySelector('p.pic_push_down').prepend(image);
        } else {
         pictures[0].prepend(image);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}();
carousel.init();
let prev = document.getElementById('prevButton'),
  next = document.getElementById('nextButton');
prev.onclick = function() {
 carousel.checkKey({keyCode:37});
};
next.onclick = function() {
 carousel.checkKey({keyCode:39});
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #line {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #line1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  
  #line2 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: thistle;
  }
  
  #line3 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  
  #line4 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: thistle;
  }
  
  #line5 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  
  #line6 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: thistle;
  }
  
  .pic_push_down {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="line">
    <div id="line1">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic1'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic2'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic3'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line4">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic4'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line5">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic5'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="line6">
      <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic6'></p>
    </div>

  </div><br>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="prevButton">left</button>
    <button id="nextButton">right</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Canvas workshop</title>

   <style>
     * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
     }
     #line {
       width: 70%;
       height: 100%;
       display: flex;
     }
     #line1 {
       width: 25%;
       background-color: wheat;
     }
     #line2 { 
       width: 25%;
       background-color: thistle;
     }
     #line3 {
       width: 25%;
       background-color: wheat;
     }
     #line4 {
       width: 25%;
       background-color: thistle;
     }
     #line5 {
       width: 25%;
       background-color: wheat;
     }
     #line6 {
       width: 25%;
       background-color: thistle;
     }
     .pic_push_down {
       margin-left: 0%;
       margin-right: 0%;
       margin-top: 0%;
     }
   </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="line">
      <div id="line1">
        <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic1'></p>
      </div>
      <div id="line2">
        <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic2'></p>
      </div>
      <div id="line3">
        <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic3'></p>
      </div>
      <div id="line4">
        <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic4'></p>
      </div>
      <div id="line5">
        <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic5'></p>
      </div>
      <div id="line6">
        <p class="pic_push_down" id='pic6'></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
      <button id="prev"><=</button>
      <button id="next">=></button>
    </div>

  <script>
    let link = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Rooster02.jpg',
        img = '<img id="image" src="'+link+'" width="180px">',
        i = 1,
        pic = document.getElementById('pic'+i.toString()).innerHTML = img;

    function next_button() {
      if (i < 6) {
        pic = document.getElementById('pic'+i.toString()).innerHTML = "";
        i++;
        pic = document.getElementById('pic'+i.toString()).innerHTML = img;
      }
    }

    function prev_button() {
      if (i > 1) {
        pic = document.getElementById('pic'+i.toString()).innerHTML = "";
        i--;
        pic = document.getElementById('pic'+i.toString()).innerHTML = img;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
      next_button();  
    };

    document.getElementById("prev").onclick = function() {
      prev_button();
    };

  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

А ещё можно так.